# Transforming data in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to convert the data in the name field to a set of random characters. For example, there was data from `Andrey Smith` - it should become `6E03EC3B 9269B806`. Now for some reason my script replaces the entire line with one word, but it should be as I indicated above. What needs to be changed in my query?

```
DECLARE @NewNames TABLE (ID INT, Name NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO @NewNames (ID, Name)
SELECT ID, (
    SELECT TOP 1 LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), NEWID()), CHARINDEX('-', CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), NEWID())) - 1)
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(Name, ' ')
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')
AS NewName
FROM dbo.[user];

UPDATE u
SET u.Name = nn.Name
FROM dbo.[user] u
JOIN @NewNames nn ON u.ID = nn.ID;
```

Comment: You're asking for the `TOP (1)`, so you are only going to get one word. If you're don't want 1 row (word) don't limit yourself to 1.

Comment: try a [user defined function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql) to make the process easier and more maintainable. Put your conversion in the fn, then call it like `update u set u.name = fn(u.name)` without temporary tables or xml parsing. You can even create the fn using C# if your conversion is particulary tricky for SQL.

Comment: A TVF would be a much better option over a scalar function, @gbjbaanb .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `STRING_AGG` it is possible to concatenate strings, like this:

```sql
SELECT ID, (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), NEWID()), CHARINDEX('-', CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), NEWID())) - 1),' ')
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(Name, ' ')
  )
AS NewName
FROM Usertbl
```

Here is the SQL fiddle:

https://sqlfiddle.com/sql-server/online-compiler?id=c6d337ba-7d94-4cac-85c1-b1bad1a170ea